# How to map object data in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I'am getting API data which is in the form of as follows:

```
data: [
"_id": "123abc",
"pics": {
"pic1": "URL of pic1"
"pic2":"URL of pic2"
},
"_id": "234adc",
"pics": {
"pic1": "URL of pic1"
"pic2":"URL of pic2"
},
"_id": "678adc",
"pics": {
"pic1": "URL of pic1"
"pic2":"URL of pic2"
},
"_id": "990efg",
"pics": {
"pic1": "URL of pic1"
"pic2":"URL of pic2"
},

]
```

I want to display data for pic1 from each object. I have tried with data.map(newData => (

))
but, getting pics as undefined. What is the best solution?

Comment: It could be a copy/paste typo, but your data isn't formatted correctly. The first element in the array, `_id`, doesn't have any nested "pic" properties, but the second element ***does***. This continues the every-other pattern. Please try to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your attempt and describe in a bit more detail what isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

For your case should be:

```
const arrayPics1 = data.map(item => item.pics.pic1)
```

Comment: See my comment above. This fails on first element `"_id"` doesn't have a `pics` property, but it doesn't matter since the data is malformed and the code wouldn't run anyway. You are assuming data shape.